# ZeroMQ dealer socket doesn't work under Elixir (using Erlang's chumak)

Tags: erlang, elixir, zeromq, chumak

I want to communicate between Elixir and Python. I don't want to use NIFs and stuff - I prefer loosely coupled using zeroMQ as this will allow me to use other languages than Python later. I am using the [chumak](https://github.com/zeromq/chumak) library which is a native implementation of zeromq in Erlang, and seems well maintained. I have used it successfully in the past for pub sub.

Apart from pub-sub, I'm finding that req-rep and req-router sockets work fine. However dealer-router does not. This is really important because only dealer and router give you true async in zeromq.

Here is the python code for the router side:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
rout = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
rout.bind("tcp://192.168.1.192:8760")
```

Here is the Elixir req code which works fine...

```
iex(1)> {ok, sock1} = :chumak.socket(:req, 'reqid')
{:ok, #PID<0.162.0>}
iex(2)> {ok, _peer} = :chumak.connect(sock1, :tcp, '192.168.1.192', 8760)
{:ok, #PID<0.164.0>}
iex(3)> :chumak.send(sock1, 'hello from req socket')
:ok
```

.... because I get it on the Python side:

```
In [5]: xx = rout.recv_multipart()
In [6]: xx
Out[6]: ['reqid', '', 'hello from req socket']
```

However, here is what I get if I try a dealer socket on the Elixir side:

```
iex(4)> {ok, sock2} = :chumak.socket(:dealer, 'dealid')                  
{:ok, #PID<0.170.0>}
iex(5)> {ok, _peer} = :chumak.connect(sock2, :tcp, '192.168.1.192', 8760)
{:ok, #PID<0.172.0>}
iex(6)> :chumak.send(sock2, 'hello from dealer socket')
{:error, :not_implemented_yet}
iex(7)> :chumak.send_multipart(sock2, ['a', 'b', 'hello from dealer socket'])

22:13:38.705 [error] GenServer #PID<0.172.0> terminating
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :chumak_protocol.encode_more_message/3
    (chumak) /home/tbrowne/code/elixir/chutest/deps/chumak/src/chumak_protocol.erl:676: :chumak_protocol.encode_more_message('a', :null, %{})
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (chumak) /home/tbrowne/code/elixir/chutest/deps/chumak/src/chumak_protocol.erl:664: :chumak_protocol.encode_message_multipart/3
    (chumak) /home/tbrowne/code/elixir/chutest/deps/chumak/src/chumak_peer.erl:159: :chumak_peer.handle_cast/2
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:616: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:686: :gen_server.handle_msg/6
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: {:"$gen_cast", {:send, ['a', 'b', 'hello from dealer socket'], {#PID<0.160.0>, #Reference<0.79795089.2401763329.172383>}}}
State: {:state, :ready, '192.168.1.192', 8760, :client, [], :dealer, 'dealid', [], {3, 0}, #Port<0.4968>, {:decoder, :ready, 0, nil, nil, {:some, 3}, {:some, 0}, %{}, :null, false}, #PID<0.170.0>, {[], []}, [], false, false, false, :null, %{}}

22:13:38.710 [info]  [:unhandled_handle_info, {:module, :chumak_socket}, {:msg, {:EXIT, #PID<0.172.0>, {:function_clause, [{:chumak_protocol, :encode_more_message, ['a', :null, %{}], [file: '/home/tbrowne/code/elixir/chutest/deps/chumak/src/chumak_protocol.erl', line: 676]}, {:lists, :mapfoldl, 3, [file: 'lists.erl', line: 1354]}, {:chumak_protocol, :encode_message_multipart, 3, [file: '/home/tbrowne/code/elixir/chutest/deps/chumak/src/chumak_protocol.erl', line: 664]}, {:chumak_peer, :handle_cast, 2, [file: '/home/tbrowne/code/elixir/chutest/deps/chumak/src/chumak_peer.erl', line: 159]}, {:gen_server, :try_dispatch, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 616]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 686]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 247]}]}}}]
```

As you can see I get this huge error on the :chumak.send_multipart, while :chumak.send doesn't even work. What's going on here?

The dealer socket works fine by the way from the Python side:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
deal = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
deal.setsockopt_string(zmq.IDENTITY, u"Thomas")
deal.connect("tcp://192.168.1.192:8760")
deal.send("hello from python deal")
```

Now on router side:

```
In [5]: xx = rout.recv_multipart()
In [6]: xx
Out[6]: ['reqid', '', 'hello from req socket']
In [7]: dd = rout.recv_multipart()
In [8]: dd
Out[8]: ['Thomas', 'hello from python deal']
```

So I'm wondering if I have a syntax, or type error, in my Elixir chumak dealer socket, or if it's simply a bug. I have tried this on both amd64 and armv7l architectures and the problem is identical.

All the elixir code is based on the Erlang version in the [chumak example](https://github.com/zeromq/chumak/blob/master/examples/router_with_dealer.erl) for dealer-router.

My mix.exs deps looks like this:

```
 [
      {:chumak, "~> 1.2"},
      {:msgpack, "~> 0.7.0"}

 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only obvious thing I see is your use of send_multipart. Its signature in the source:

```
-spec send_multipart(SocketPid::pid(), [Data::binary()]) -> ok.
```

you are doing this:

```
:chumak.send_multipart(sock2, ['a', 'b', 'hello from dealer socket'])

------------
iex(2)> is_binary('a')
false
iex(3)> is_binary('hello from dealer socket')
false
```

Otherwise, I can not see much of a difference between your code and the example code that is in chumak's repo.

Comment: Nice. I've just tested it using :chumak.send_multipart(sock2, [<<1, 2>>, <<3, 4>>] and that works fine. So basically I had a type error. I thought I needed to use _erlang binaries_ via the single quote mechanism but actually it will take Elixir binaries including for example ["123", "456"]. Awesome.